# Query between a list of keys and a key to geojson object

Tags: sql, postgresql

Apologies if the title is a bit confusing what I have are two tables. One table hold the FIPS (county code for USA) followed by the list of geoids or tract_numbers that fall into that associated FIPS or County. Here is what the table looks like

[image]

I have a second table that holds each geoid or tract_number with their associated geojson object that is in the geometry column. The table looks like this

[image]

What I need to do is build a query that will grab each geojson object for each associated FIPS/county code. I hope this makes sense.

I am not exactly sure if this is the most efficient in terms the way the data is stored so I am up for having that discussion. Otherwise, I am a bit lost as to how to build this query. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that one `track_number` can only be referenced with one `FIPS`: The most efficient way would be to reference the `FIPS` table directly in the `trac_number` table as a foreign key. The way you're doing it is pretty hard to create indexes and it is also very hard to maintain the column `county_tract_map`, as it needs to be updated every time you insert or delete a record in the `track_number` table.

Comment: @JimJones I see, so would you suggest I just duplicate the FIPS for each geoid/tract_number in the first table?

Comment: Yes, fpr a 1:N relationship it would be my suggestion. In case there are multiple FIPS for a single geoid it would create a N:N relationship, which requires an intermediate table to store both identifiers.